# CPU usage is much higher when multithreaded program is run from visual studio

Tags: c#, multithreading

I found this really strange. I was testing a program that create 1500 thread concurrently. When I run this program from visual studio 2013, cpu usage goes higher (around 60%) but when i run the exe, cpu usage remains below 10%.

```
    static ManualResetEvent _doneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static int _numerOfThreadsNotYetCompleted = 1500;
    private static readonly object ob= new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> taskList = new List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
        Console.Read();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1500; ++i)
        {
            var j = i;
            var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
            Thread obj = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                lock (ob)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(_numerOfThreadsNotYetCompleted);
                    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref _numerOfThreadsNotYetCompleted) == 0)
                        _doneEvent.Set();
                }       
            });
            obj.Start();
        }
        _doneEvent.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("All done.");
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I believe it may be because of the extra overhead that comes with the debugging features on Visual Studio.. These overhead are not there if you build the Release version and run it standalone.

Comment: The only thing this code really does is keep the debugger busy.  Starting and stopping threads generate debugger notifications, you see them in the Output window.

Comment: `When I run this program from visual studio 2013` What do you mean? Do you run it from VS or debug?

Comment: Remove `Thread.Sleep`. Also, there seems to be a few redundant lines of code...

Comment: Thanks for the replies, this code behaves the same in case I run it in release mode from VS. Thread.Sleep is just to simulate the time taking task.

Comment: @Pragmatic You need to run it in Release mode **and** without the debugger, i.e. Ctrl+F5, not just F5.

Comment: @svick, I ran it in release mode and without the debugger. Still behavior is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what is supposed to happen?  You create 1500 threads and then wait on _doneEvent.  That's going to take less than 10 seconds.  The threads immediately hit the Sleep(10000) and so nothing happens.  At 9 secs, you have 1500 sleepy threads and 0 CPU use. At 10+ a bit, all 1500 threads become ready and start thrashing about on the ob lock, trying to output their tiny bit of text.  Your program appears to do nothing except wait for ages and then serially exercise syscalls.